# ¿Cómo puedo organizar el nombre de una variable que está en un archivo TXT en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, txt

quisiera saber cómo puedo organizar el nombre de las variables, ya que estás al leer el archivo txt el programa las lee y las deja con algunos símbolos, para ser más claro con la duda que tengo:

Lee los datos:

`setwd("C:/Users/BORJA10/Desktop/TEP")`

`data <- read.csv("SB11_20192.txt", sep = "¬")`

Aquí ya he leído los datos, pero cuando veo los nombre de las variables me aparecen de la siguiente manera:

`View(data)`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, en la variable **FAMI_EDUCACIONOPADRE** hay datos donde debería ir **"técnica o tecnológica completa"** pero el pone símbolos. Sé que tiene que ver con el UTF, pero no sé cómo organizarlo. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solo tienes que agregar:  fileEncoding="utf-8" después de sep = "¬", y así se soluciona tu problema.

```
data <- read.csv("SB11_20192.txt", sep = "¬", fileEncoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Sí, eso vi en un video, igual muchas gracias.